# Trying to simplify a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would really appreciate any help trying to simplify a MySQL query. The purpose of the query is to retrieve messages from a messages table (users_messages) which has the following columns: message_id, from_id, to_id, message_content, date_sent.

The from_id and to_id need to join a users table (users) which has these columns: user_id, user_username.

Also I should mention that there is a blocked users table (users_blocked) which filters out any messages should the user_id feature in this table.

All this works fine and messages are ordered with the newest first which is what I want. My only problem is that it's not pulling the corresponding 'message_content'. i.e. it's pulling the most recent date, but not the most recent message.

Perhaps I need a different approach (e.g. subqueries) but I can not get my head around it.

Here is the query:

```
select m.message_content,
    if(from_id < to_id, concat(from_id,to_id), concat(to_id,from_id)) as ft,
    if (from_id = $my_id, to_id, from_id) as other_id,
    max(date_sent) as most_recent
from users_messages m
    left join users_blocked ub1 on (from_id = ub1.blocked_id and ub1.user_id = $my_id)
    left join users_blocked ub2 on (to_id = ub2.blocked_id and ub2.user_id = $my_id)
where
    (from_id = $my_id or to_id = $my_id)
    and ub1.blocked_id is null
    and ub2.blocked_id is null
group by
    ft
order by
    most_recent desc
```

Sorry, here are the table structures:

users

```
user_id    user_username
1          Simon
2          Amber
3          Tom
```

users_messages

```
message_id    from_id    to_id    date_sent             message_content
1             1          2        2012-07-04 11:52:12   Hello
2             1          2        2012-07-04 12:32:24   Another message
3             1          2        2012-07-04 14:00:00   Hello again
```

users_blocked

```
user_id    blocked_id
1          3
```

Comment: Please include your table structure(s). Also - it's returning `message_content` but it isn't the correct value? Or it's not returning anything?

Comment: That's not too bad. Hell, you can read it all without scrolling, which is always a bonus!

Comment: not terrible but I would probably just get an array of blocked users and do a not in for the from_id

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem is that it's returning the most recent date, but the first message content. i.e. Date: 2012-07-04 14:00:00, Message: Hello

Comment: A little note: Do you plan to have a huge number of datasets in your `users_messages` (i know huge is a relative word)? But if so you should keep a look at your `GROUP BY ft` part. This could be a bottleneck later because mysql could not use any index to optimize the `group by` which could become slow.

Comment: Yeah I plan on having a large number of messages in this table so I should really be looking at an alternative approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select m.message_content,
       x.ft,
       x.other_id,
       x.most_recent
from (select if(from_id < to_id, concat(from_id,to_id), concat(to_id,from_id)) as ft,
             if(from_id = $my_id, to_id, from_id) as other_id,
             max(date_sent) as most_recent
      from users_messages um
      left join users_blocked ub1 
        on (um.from_id = ub1.blocked_id and ub1.user_id = $my_id)
      left join users_blocked ub2 
        on (um.to_id = ub2.blocked_id and ub2.user_id = $my_id)
      where ub1.blocked_id is null and ub2.blocked_id is null and
            (um.from_id = $my_id or um.to_id = $my_id)
      group by ft) x
join users_messages m
     on m.date_sent = x.most_recent and 
        m.from_id in ($my_id, x.other_id) and 
        m.to_id in ($my_id, x.other_id)
order by
    x.most_recent desc
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea0ab/1).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried this and I received an error "Unknown column 'm.from_id' in 'where clause'". I changed "users_messages" to "users_messages m" in the sub query and now this returns 0 results.

Comment: @SimonKing: I have made some changes - try now.

Comment: Spot on. Absolutely perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming SimonKing wants, message content from users_messages table which includes following condition,

1. Users should not blocked either directions,
2. The **most recent messages** transferred between the users

So that, I modified Mark Bannister query as follows,

```
SELECT temp.* FROM  (
SELECT um.*, concat(um.from_id,to_id) as direction FROM userMessages um
LEFT JOIN userBlocked ub1 ON um.from_id = ub1.user_id AND um.to_id = ub1.blocked_id
LEFT JOIN userBlocked ub2 ON um.to_id = ub2.user_id AND um.from_id = ub2.blocked_id 
WHERE ub1.user_id is null AND ub1.blocked_id is null AND ub2.user_id is null AND ub2.blocked_id is null
ORDER BY um.date_sent DESC
) temp
GROUP BY direction
```

SQL fiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdc77/1/0

Comment: This relies on an observed but undocumented behaviour in MySQL, which may not work in future versions; it has already been removed from MariaDB (the open-source fork of MySQL).

Comment: @Mark Bannister, Give me some url to get further information about this

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, the main problem of this request is that result contains only first dates, not messages. To fix this you can do this:

1. make prepared data set which will have most recent dates:

   select to_id, from_id, max(date_sent) as most_recent
       from users_messages m
           left join users_blocked ub on ub.user_id = $my_id 
               and ub.blocked_id in (to_id, from_id)
       where
           (from_id = $my_id or to_id = $my_id)
           and ub.blocked_id is null
       group by
           to_id, from_id
       order by
           most_recent desc

I see you groping data by two collumns to_id, from_id. This subquery isn't best place to calculate things like:

```
if(from_id < to_id, concat(from_id,to_id), concat(to_id,from_id)) as ft
```

1. Then just select other needed data from users_messages, which matches our to_id, from_id and recent_date from prepared table:

   select um.* from

   ```
   (
   select to_id, from_id, max(date_sent) as most_recent
   from users_messages m
   left join users_blocked ub on ub.user_id = 1
   and ub.blocked_id in (to_id, from_id)
   where
   (from_id = 1 or to_id = 1)
   and ub.blocked_id is null
   group by
   to_id, from_id
   order by
   most_recent desc
   ) as prepared_messages
   left join users_messages um on um.from_id = prepared_messages.from_id
   and um.to_id = prepared_messages.to_id
   and um.date_sent = prepared_messages.most_recent
   ```